# Javascript Code Keeps Resetting When Page Is Refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a major problem with some `JavaScript` code. The code itself works perfectly when you're on the page, it does what its meant to do. However when the code is set to trigger a table I have within the script it triggers and displays the table but if I refresh or close the page and come back the whole thing has been set to its original start position. This is a shame because it's a good script if only I could fix this issue. I've attached a link to the current script. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/JamesDouglas/xwshqfL1/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but you should include the (relevant) JavaScript in your question. We're not (usually) willing to follow links around the internet just to help you. Incidentally, the reason you couldn't format that link as a link is because you *didn't include the code in your question*, next time: please do. This time, please [edit]. @Matyas: unless that was meant to be comedy, please read the question.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is a client side scripting language. It exists only in the current browser. Even more, it exist only within one refresh.

So when a page gets refreshed then the code dies, and a new one start when the page is loaded the second time. That is why the script starts all over again.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript lives inside the browser, lifecycle of code written with that starts when the document (HTML page referring to those JavaScript) and goes until the page is reloaded. This is not an issue, it's how it's designed.

If you want to retain your client side state, and still perform server call, you should use the technique known as AJAX, which uses a specific object known as XMLHttpRequest to perform a server call without reloading the entire page.

Just google for AJAX and you will find plenty of information on how to do that.

It's not exactly clear what you mean by 'trigger a table' but if you post some code examples we might be able to help bit more.

Here is MDN link for AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX